# Dumping LDAP - Sizelimit Exceeded

Tags: ldap, dump

When I'm LDAP searching, I got error: "LDAP: error code 4 - Sizelimit Exceeded". How can I dump all the data without changing LDAP server settings?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this article](http://jeftek.com/219/avoid-changing-the-maxpagesize-ldap-query-policy/) helps. Once I needed to retrieve records from Active Directory configured to return only 1000 records using JNDI; [Active Directory, Paging and Range](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=578347&tstart=60) looks close to what I'm dealt with.

Answer (score 1):

The directory server imposes a limit on:

- the number of objects to return from a search
- the amount of time spent on a search
- the number of entries to examine when creating the candidate list

Depending on the server, the limits can be imposed by global configuration, via a client connection policy, or based on the authentication identity. The result in the search response indicates that a partial number of results were returned to the client. The client can (and should) impose a size limit and a time limit as part of a search request, but these limits, known as client-requested limits, cannot override the server limits.

Applications must not assume that the contents of a directory server can be trawled or retrieved, not only does such an action manifest security risks, it deleterious to the performance of the directory and adversely impacts other clients on the directory. A properly configured directory server will not allow listing of all the contents of all the base DNs it hosts.

My [blog entry](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/mastering-ldapsearch/) has some discussion about search request and search response.